# Make Session expire

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using `authentication mode=forms` in web.config file. Because it is a secure application so I want to expire my session in 5 minutes. Right now I am doing it in programming in codebehind.
Is there any other easy way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it in Web.config file. This will expire `Session`

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="5" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Other option is, This will expire `cookie`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" loginUrl="Login.aspx" protection="All" timeout="5" path="/" slidingExpiration="true">
   </forms>
</authentication>
```

Comment: This injects the session value in my url.

Comment: @Nick Setting `cookieless="true"` is what injects the session value in your url. You don't need to specify that setting.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it from c#

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1d3t3c61.aspx, there is timeout parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
          <forms timeout="5"/>
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Timeout of 95 years? That almost deserves -1 for the careless approach.

Comment: I'm not sure why I wrote 50000000, even if timeout expected seconds that would be too long.